# Points on a ggplot map coloured with a gradient based on data

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapping, data-visualization

I'm trying to plot points on a map of the UK, where the size of the points changes depending on the data.

At the moment, I have a map where the points are bigger or smaller depending on the data. This is helpful, but due to some points being quite close to each other, it's sometimes a little tricky to make out, especially if a large point is blocking out others.

Therefore, I want to adapt what I have so that the points are differentiated on a colour gradient - so for e.g. going from white at the the lowest to blue at the highest.

Here is part of my data file:

```
structure(list(V1 = c("St George's", "Sheffield", "Plymouth", 
"Exeter", "King's College London", "East Anglia"), 
Sample = c(183L, 139L, 106L, 128L, 152L, 178L), 
Total = c(417L, 342L, 350L, 520L, 659L, 875L), 
Response = c(43.9, 40.6, 30.3, 24.6, 23.1, 20.3), 
Lat = c(51.427194, 53.380941, 50.415735, 50.737137, 51.511486, 52.621921), 
Long = c(-0.174503, -1.487947, -4.110571, -3.535147, -0.115997, 1.239176)), 
.Names = c("V1", "Sample", "Total", "Response", "Lat", "Long"), 
row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Once I've got the datafile loaded, I do this:

```
UK <- map_data(map = "world", region = "UK")

ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = UK, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
  geom_point(data = unidata, aes(x = Long, y = Lat, size = Response), col = "red") +
  coord_map()
```

I tried changing size to fill, but that gets me uniformly sized points that are all black.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried changing alpha? For example: `geom_point(data = unidata, aes(x = Long, y = Lat, size = Response), col = "red", alpha = 0.3)`. This is what I usually do :-)

Comment: You could also "jitter" the points slightly to offset them. e.g.  `aes(x = long + rnorm(1, 0, .01)`

Comment: With the provided date the problem is not really reproducible. The above mentioned could be solutions but not necessarily.

Comment: Thanks everyone. PoGibas, definitely helpful to have the transparency as an option. I'd like to crack the gradient option though! Alex, sorry it's not reproducible - I used dput to get the head of the data set. Can you let me know what additional information would help?

Comment: maybe try `shape = 1` in `geom_shape` to get open circles

Comment: Sorry, I realised my question wasn't clear enough so I have updated it. I'm specifically looking for a way to make the points coloured on a gradient to show the data, instead of my current way of changing the size of the points.

Comment: @Megan The default shape in `geom_point` is coloured by `col` rather than `fill`, hence setting `fill = Response` in your aesthetic mapping achieves nothing. You can use `col = Response` instead. Or, if you want the points to be coloured based on Response while retaining a red outline, trying adding `shape = 21`. It's one of the few shapes that accepts both a colour and a fill parameter. See [here](http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/shape) for illustration.

Comment: @Z.Lin thanks, I have tried this and it basically works! I had to move col back into the brackets, so the line is "geom_point(data = unidata, aes(x = Long + rnorm(1, 0, 0.1), y = Lat, col = unidata$Response), alpha = 0.3) +". If you post this answer I'll accept it :)